# How to get PyCListView object from an existing listview handle?

Tags: pywin32

The listview is in another process, I get the listview handle by FindWindow and enumerate child window.

I want to get PyClistView object because it has convenient functions like 'GetColumn', 'GetItem'.

Comment: From where? Inside the application or outside?

Comment: outside the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then probably you need GUI automation tool like [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/). Working with ListView controls in another process is already simplified here. And it's Python as well.